# Removing the text before an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Imagine this scenario:

```
<span>Item 1</span> | <span>Item 2</span>
```

How can I target the | and remove it? Also, assume I always need to remove the | before the `span` with "Item 2" in it, and the list can grow with items being added before OR after "Item 2." All new items will be enclosed within `span` and they'll be separated by |.

Comment: Do you need to remove the spaces too or ONLY the single `|` character?

Comment: Is this a string of text, or part of the DOM?

Comment: Yes, is this already in the page? Or is it just in a variable in javascript?

Comment: Instead of using an actual `|`, I'd just use CSS and style the `border` property.

Comment: manipulating text nodes is one of the things jquery doesn't exactly excel in. Perhaps it would be easier using native DOM.

Comment: The HTML is already outputted and I'll be manipulating it with jQuery. I can't change the initial output, or the fact that a | is being used. I just have to target the | that's before "Item 2" and remove it. Spaces aren't a huge deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Item 2') {
        $(this.previousSibling).remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spFUG/2/

Comment: If I could manipulate the html or what is outputting it, I'd be in heaven. *lol* Unfortunately, I cannot do this. The HTML is out, I have to manipulate it as-is. I can't change it on that level.

Comment: Looks good. Demo is good. Doesn't work for me. Not sure why. Much thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Are you using the exact same code and jQuery version and so on?

Comment: No errors being kicked out by the console. The | just remains. Here is a jsfiddle I've made using the exact page html (just with dummy text): http://jsfiddle.net/uFawq/  - and it works. But on the actual page it does not. I imagine the exact text I am using in the IF is not being recognized.

Just bear in mind that it's not my html, so I cannot change it. I have to manipulate it using this override jquery file.

Comment: So you need to debug on the actual page. Do the following in the loop `console.log($(this).text() == ' Some-Name2 From-Where - City, Illinois: (555) 555-5555 ')`. Thats the test for the if branch and there need to be at least one `true` output. If not, log only `$(this).text()` to come closer. If jQuery versions and everything else is matching, this could be just a small thing. ;)

Comment: Debugging on the actual page, turns out there is more than just a | before the `span`. I didn't think it would register spaces as a text or other node. Using two removes did the trick. To be safe, given how badly the text string I was testing was being output, I compared after stripping spaces and returns using a regular expression. In all, this method of yours worked. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

manipulating text nodes is one of the things jquery doesn't exactly excel in. Incidentally, the native browser API does this very well. Even if you don't want to use it regularly, this time you probably should. `previousSibling` selects the previous node, be it a text node, a comment node or an element node. It's probably safe to assume it's always the text node that you want to remove :

```
var $elem = $(":contains('Item 2')");

$elem.map(function(){ //select the preceding node to any element we want to remove
  return this.previousSibling
}).addBack() // select the original element node as well
.remove(); // remove both
```

note that `addBack` was added in jQuery 1.8. If you are using an older version, use `andSelf` instead. If you want to remove *only* the text node, drop `addBack` entirely.

Comment: Looks interesting. The fact that I can use this to remove a text node, being so the browser API seems more appropriate in this case, is ideal. I went ahead and tried this with the Chrome console, but it threw this error: "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addBack'"

Comment: @user1729506 if you are using an old version of jQuery, use `andSelf` instead. `addBack` was added in 1.8 .

Comment: `$().map` _does_ return a jQuery object. I've just checked.

Comment: Now returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: @user1729506 show me your code. A syntax error is hardly my fault.

Comment: I used your code as-is, replacing only "Item 2" with the real text. I went ahead and removed .addback/andself per your final suggestion. That removed all errors. But it still doesn't remove the |.

Comment: `.remove()` does work for text nodes. Perhaps there's no text node just before the element you want to remove? Note that comment nodes do count.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Here's some direct javascript that would remove all " | " from the code

```
var parent = $('span').parent().get(0), children = parent.childNodes, node;

    for (node = 0;node < children.length;node++){
        if (children[node].data === " | "){
             parent.removeChild(children[node]);
        }
    }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vg3pc/

Answer (score 0):

`.contents` finds text nodes.

```
$("#container").contents().each(function () {
    //Text node
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
       $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQsk5/

Comment: You don't want to remove _all_ text nodes

Comment: @JanDvorak it doesn't; it only removes child text nodes

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this know to remove "|" only?

Comment: @user1729506 it doesn't it removes the text nodes from `body` (in my example), but they do not get removed from the spans so they remain in the document.  This should work for your purposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent of the `span`s and use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) along with `.replace()`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('span:first-child').parent().html($('span:first-child').parent().html().replace(/\|/g, ''))
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/5F3kf/2/

Answer (score 0):

Grab `spans`. Remove everything. Put spans back (`.join`ed as you choose).

```
<div class='container'>
  <span>Item 1</span> | <span>Item 2</span>
</div>
```

.

```
var $c = $(".container");
var $spans = $c.find("span");
var htmlSpans = [];
$spans.each(function(){
   htmlSpans.push($(this).prop("outerHTML"));
});

$c.empty();
$c.append(htmlSpans.join(" "));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u59Uz/

EDIT:
Dirty hack using same logic to handle this very specific case. Regex replace handles 0 or more spaces before and after the pipe.

```
var $c = $(".container");
var html = $c.prop("outerHTML");

$c.empty();
$c.append(html.replace(/\s*\|\s*<span>Item 2/,"<span>Item 2" ));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TnXB7/1/

Comment: This seems to remove all instances of |, not specifically targeted ones. I need to target and remove only the one that appears before "Item 2."

Comment: Right, sorry I misunderstood. Perhaps one of the other answers will help you out.

Comment: Just expanding the answer to address the specific target, but I think the `previousSibling` approaches are better.